# Azure Data Factory- Copy specific files from multiple Parent folders from FTP Server

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to copy the .ZIP files from FTP Server to Azure DataLake.
I need to copy specific files from specific parent folders(Totally i have 6 parent folders in the FTP)and this pipeline needs to scheduled.
So how should i provide the parameters such that Pipeline should select only the specific files from the different folders?

I have used Metadata Activity and tried creating pipelines but not sure how to provide the pipeline to pick only specific files!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory supports compress/decompress data during copy. When you specify compression property in an input dataset, the copy activity read the compressed data from the source and decompress it; and when you specify the property in an output dataset, the copy activity compress then write data to the sink.

For example:

Read .zip file from FTP server, decompress it to get the files inside, and land those files in Azure Data Lake Store. You define an input FTP dataset with the compression type property as ZipDeflate.

For more details, please reference: [Compression support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support).

Here's the tutorial about [Copy data from FTP server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp).

Other format dataset
To copy data from FTP in ORC/Avro/JSON/Binary format, the following properties are supported in this link: [Other format dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp#other-format-dataset).

[image]

**Tips:**

1. To copy all files under a folder, specify **folderPath** only.
2. To copy a single file with a given name, specify **folderPath** with folder part and **fileName** with file name.
3. To copy a subset of files under a folder, specify **folderPath** with folder part and **fileName** with wildcard filter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the filter activity to filter only the folders / files that you need. I think you'll need 2 loops:

Loop 1: get metadata of folders -> Filter required folders -> foreach pipeline with loop 2
Loop 2: get meta data of files of files -> Filter required files -> copy required files